# Can't save to database if i incude view with Html.RenderPartial

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this model FileUpload.cs

```
public class FileUpload
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

public class FileUploadCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
}

public class FileUploadLanguage
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

I have generated Controllers and Views with CRUD

I can add new languages if I visit: http://localhost:xxx/fileuploadlanguages/create

I want to have a settings page (one view) where I can add category and languages and uploads files.

File structure

```
Controllers
-- FileUploadLanguagesController.cs
Models
-- Fileupload.cs (the code above)
Views
--Fileuploads.cs
----Create
----Delete
----Settings
--FileUploadLanguages.cs
----Create
----Delete
```

I have this in Settings (nothing else)

```
<h1>Upload files</h1>
@{Html.RenderPartial("Create");}

<h2>Managing language</h2>
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/FileUploadLanguages/Create.cshtml");}
```

I can upload files and the see the "Managing language" page on settings but when I press save nothing happens. Nothing is saved to the database and no error.

And if I change to

```
<h2>Managing language</h2>
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/FileUploadLanguages/Index.cshtml");}
```

I get null error

Comment: If the view is rendered then your problem is with your form and not your partial.

Comment: You need to show the views and the method you posting back to